# Not asked for AD credentials in package manager, getting 401 error from feed

Tags: active-directory, visual-studio-2017, nuget

We are using DevOps for our NuGet feed & VSO repos.  I recently switched from using my personal MSN account to using my AD account.  I can access DevOps fine and I can access the NuGet feed URL via a browser and I get back the expected JSON, so everything seems fine there.

In the Solution Package Manager, when I try to browse our NuGet source I am seeing the Microsoft Sign In Prompt.  I type in my AD email and I see the "taking you to your organization's sign in page" message, but then I get the same Sign In prompt.  If I type it in again, it gives up and I see a 401 error in the output window for my feed's URL...the same one I can browse to and see results.

We have a Microsoft resource we work with and we both have gone through every article we could find to fix this.  When we exhausted that search he decided to to give me access to his own private NuGet feed to see what happened. I added that to my sources and went back to the Solution Package Manger and I get the Microsft Sign In page.  After entering my email, and seeing the "taking you to your organization's sign in page" message, I am taken to...my organization's sign in page! I am prompted for my AD username/password, and, once entered, I can browse the feed.

I am not sure if my AD account has invalid credentials cached out there or not.  But I need a way to get the Package Manager in VS to prompt me for the AD username/password for my feed.

Storing the credentials in the Nuget.Config file or using PAT are not options.  Yes, they do work, but as you can see from the second test, they are absolutely not needed for me to consume a private feed.

Also of note: when testing this my manager made me the Nuget project administrator.

Comment: What is your main issue? Do you want to log on the username and password each time when you access the private nuget feed?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, they do work, but as you can see from the second test, they are
> absolutely not needed for me to consume a private feed.

**Actually**, when you enter your AD username and password successfully, VS will store that info into the related cache file by default and when you test it the second time, it will read the cache and you do not have to enter the username and password again.

The cache file is under

```
C:\Users\xxx(current user account)\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AccountStore.json
```

**Solution**

So if you want to enter username and password for security each time you access the private nuget feed, you should delete it manually and then restart VS.Apart from it, there is no other function.

**Besides**, you can create a batch file to delete this file quickly.

write this in the batch file:

```
echo Batch to delete file

del "C:\Users\xxx(current user account)\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AccountStore.json" /s /f /q

echo Done!
```

Every time you run this batch file, you should restart VS and then do further operation.

Comment: That does not work for me.  It was one of the first things I tried, as over a dozen people suggested that for permissions issues.  And besides that, this is AD and both of those NuGet projects rely on my AD credentials to access.  So if one works, why would one feed fail with a 401?

Comment: Before doing this, do you delete the `<packageSourceCredentials />` node in the `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuge\NuGet.config`, if you add this in the `nuget.config` file, deleting the `AccountStore.json` will not require you to re-enter your credentials, You should  first make sure that `nuget.config` file does not have that node, then deleting `AccountStore.json` file to test again.

Comment: I do not have that node.  I've deleted the entire .IdentityService folder a dozen times now, along with other files/folders as directed by Microsoft, to no avail.  This bug is specific to VS2017 when connecting to a feed that is in AD mixed mode (i.e., not connected to an AD source).

VS2019 does not have this issue.  Microsoft claimed they fixed this bug previously in VS2017 though..